# Use external link in img src in flask jinja2

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, jinja2, web-deployment

I want to use an external link as an image in img tag in HTML in flask.
I know how to do it by keeping the images in static folder but my case is different.

I want to do something like below code in index.html:

```
<body>
    <h1>external image</h1>
    <img src={{url_for('static',filename='https://unsplash.com/photos/uUVkzxDR1D0')}}
      alt="No image">
</body>
```

My Flask looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template

app=Flask(__name__,static_url_path='',static_folder='static',template_folder='templates')

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")
```

I tried removing the static endpoint from the url_for function as it does not makes sense to search for an external image link into static folder, but then I got the error that url_for requires an endpoint.So, I don't know how to put the image link.

> Everything is just working fine. Only the image is not getting
> rendered and I am getting the alt text, i.e., 'No Image' on screen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
<img src='https://unsplash.com/photos/uUVkzxDR1D0'
  alt="No image">
```

Of course this hotlinks that image from the remote server within your page, which some hosts may disable for their images.

Comment: I tried this approach but still there was no result, it continued to show the alt text.

Comment: I double checked, the URL you included actually leads to an HTML page on the site, which gives you options to download that image, etc.  Therefor it can't be included in an img tag.  Why not download a version of the picture, save it to your `static` directory, and build the link in the normal way with `url_for`?

Comment: @Yash If you're just looking for any old image to include, maybe take a look at [Loreum Picsum](https://picsum.photos/) which will support hotlinking as per this answer.  It's quite good because it also lets you set image dimensions via the URL.  Infact the footer of this site says it actually takes images from unsplash.

Comment: I tried with another link which didn't had that downloadable thing and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: For future visitors, another way of doing it can by setting a flask variable with the link and then using that variable in the img tag.

`{% set url='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1422422153408-a3298d6d542c?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=889&q=80' %}

<img src="{{url}}" alt="No image">`

Answer (score 0):

Within your flask app:

```
def index():
    ...
    img_url = "http://cooldomain.rofl/image.png"
    
    return render_template("index.html", img_url=img_url)
```

In your template `index.html`:

```
<html>
<img src="{{ img_url }}" alt="This is an image">
</html>
```

This way you don't need to hard code a URL into a template.